# What's a good syntax in C# for "If foo isn't null, return a property of it, otherwise null"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my little code snippet below I have a wrapper class for a simple dynamic object that, when not null, I can access two properties of, "id" and "name".  It's a Facebook object, for those playing at home.

Anyway, in my GET accessor you can see I have to check if the dynamic object I was given was null, since referencing a dynamic property on a null reference will AV.  But since I'm probably about the millionth person to do this, I assume there's a more concise and elegant way to express this.

Please enlighten me, oh mighty sages.  Thanks!

```
public class IdNamePair
{
    private dynamic _data;
    public IdNamePair(dynamic data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return (_data == null) ? null : _data.id;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (_data == null) ? null :_data.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done what you do -- you can't use the ?? shortcut here.  Curious if anyone responds with something better.

Comment: There are tons of dupes of this question on SO.  This is a very common ask...

Comment: This is OT, but if you can't do anything will null _data, why build a pair in the first place?

Comment: "A better way to do this" is a popular item on lists of features people would like to see added in C#. A suggestion I've seen a few times is to use `???` to extend `??` to cover nulls in any step of an expression, so e.g. `foo.bar.baz ??? null` would return `foo.bar.baz`, but if `foo` or `bar` or `baz` were `null`, it would return `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you have done, the only thing I would do is drop the brackets and change the evaluation:

```
return _data != null ? _data.name : null;
```

Doing it that way is just (IMVHO) slightly easier to read, but fundamentally identical to what you had.

Comment: Maybe it's not the same in c# but isn't the != unnecessary? return_data?_data.id:null;

Comment: @RobotWoods: In C# it is necessary to use `!=`.  C# won't accept it as a boolean expression otherwise, and will raise a compile error.

Comment: in c# null doesn't implicitly cast to false so the != null is required

Comment: @Robot: Nope, in C# there's no automatic conversion from reference type to bool. You're probably thinking of the C/C++ pointer-to-bool, which is more like pointer-to-integer that is true if nonzero and false if zero.

Comment: Thanks all, I wasn't sure what elements are common between C variants

Comment: Thanks.  Here's a vote for a new operator, maybe ?: 
As averse as I am to adding operators, it's such a common operation (witness the abundance of SZ() in VB).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's pretty much the way you have to do it.  Guess you're smarter than you thought :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you already have is most likely the best solution. But if you wanted, you could create an extension method like this:

```
public static TResult Select<T, TResult>(this T obj, Func<T, TResult> func)
    where T : class
    where TResult : class
{
    return obj == null ? null : func(obj);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public string Id
{
    get
    {
        return _data.Select(d => d.id);
    }
}
```

But this would make the code less readable for most people. And that method maybe should have a better name.

Doing this basically treats the nullable reference types as [Maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#Maybe_monad).